# Determine which points on the surface z² = xy + 1 are nearest to the origin of the plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-geometry

> Determine which points on the surface z² = xy + 1 are nearest to the origin of the plane.

$ xy + 1 \ge 0$ therefore the points nearest to O(0,0,0) are $z = 0, y = \frac{-1}{x}$ and $x\rightarrow0$.

Is this mathematically correct?

Is there a way to prove this using concepts from multivariable calculus?

Comment: as $x$ goes to $0$, $-1/x$ goes to $-\infty$ or $\infty$, which means your $y$ coordinate will be way too far from $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: What is "the origin of the plane"?

Comment: @lulu the point $(0,0,0)$ edit: I am guessing "of the plane" is just a mistaken phrase

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee  Oh, of course.  Thanks.  I was thinking we were trying to minimize the distance to some unspecified plane.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee is correct. This is what I meant

Comment: Hint:  this seems like a good candidate for Lagrange multipliers.  As often happens, I expect it is easier to minimize the square of the distance, so $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the constraint $G(x,y,z)=z^2-xy-1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

the distance to the origin is given by $$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+xy+1}$$
this is a function in $x,y$,differentiate with respect to $x,y$

Comment: To simplify the computations, you can differentiate $d^2(x,y)$.

Comment: This is telling me that x = 0, y = 0 and z = 1 is the nearest point. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: @Ruan $z=\pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a solution via multivariable calculus, [Dr. Graubner’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2495012/265466) is a good approach. For this problem, I think direct substitution for $z^2$ in the distance formula is much more straightforward then introducing Lagrange multipliers.

As an alternative approach, this can be solved using well-known properties of quadric surfaces: This is a nondegenerate quadric centered at the origin, so the nearest points will be along the principal axes with the greatest positive eigenvalues. Rewriting the equation of the surface as $z^2-xy=1$ gives $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&-\frac12&0\\-\frac12&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ for the matrix of the quadratic form. One can find the principal axes by inspection: they are $(0,0,1)^T$, $(1,1,0)^T$ and $(1,-1,0)^T$, with eigenvalues $1$, $-\frac12$ and $\frac12$, respectively (so that the surface is a hyperboloid of one sheet). The nearest points to the origin are therefore $\pm\frac1{\sqrt1}{(0,0,1)^T\over\|(0,0,1)^T\|}=\pm(0,0,1).$